# Error thrown when attempting to install Magento on cPanel

Tags: hosting, cpanel, vps

As stated in title, when trying to install Magento through Installatron on cPanel it throws an error everytime saying:-

"A database query has failed. Is the entered database information correct? Does the account have available disk space?

Technical information:
method = query
arguments = array (  0 => 'SELECT `user_id` FROM `mg_admin_user` WHERE `is_active`=\'1\' ORDER BY `user_id` ASC LIMIT 1',  1 => NULL,  2 => 'user_id',)"

Comment: There is a Stack Exchange community dedicated to Magento: https://magento.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Ah okay, thank you